# Inconsistency of limits

Tags: limits, special-functions, bessel-functions, wolfram-alpha

Let $I_n(x)$ and $L_n(x)$ be the modified Bessel and modified Struve functions of order $n$, respectively. Assuming $x$ is real, I am interested in the following limit: 
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{I_0(x)L_1(x) - I_1(x)L_0(x)}{x^2I_2(x)}. $$
Let's call the function $G(x)/x^2$. Now, using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20of%20(BesselI%5B0,%20x%5D*StruveL%5B1,%20x%5D%20-%20BesselI%5B1,%20x%5D*StruveL%5B0,%20x%5D)%2F(BesselI%5B2,x%5D)%20as%20x%20goes%20to%20infinity) I find that 
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} G(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{I_0(x)L_1(x) - I_1(x)L_0(x)}{I_2(x)} = -\frac{2}{\pi}. $$
So it seems like 
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{I_0(x)L_1(x) - I_1(x)L_0(x)}{x^2I_2(x)} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{G(x)}{x^2} = \left(\lim_{x\to\infty} G(x)\right)\left(\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}\right) = 0 $$
On the other hand, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20of%20(BesselI%5B0,%20x%5D*StruveL%5B1,%20x%5D%20-%20BesselI%5B1,%20x%5D*StruveL%5B0,%20x%5D)%2F(x%5E2*BesselI%5B2,x%5D)%20as%20x%20goes%20to%20infinity) gives me
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{G(x)}{x^2} = -\infty. $$
What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I managed to show (using squeeze theorem) that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} G(x)/x^2 = 0$. Nonetheless I am still interested in knowing why Wolfram Alpha is giving me the wrong limit.

Comment: For the record, Mathematica gives me a limit of 0, while the same Mathematica query entered into Wolfram Alpha (while parsed correctly) gives me $-\infty$.

Comment: @greenbagels ahhh, I actually used Mathematica before Wolfram Alpha but Mathematica still gave me $-\infty$. Hmm........

Comment: @greenbagels This is what I entered: Limit[(BesselI[0, x]*StruveL[1, x] - 
    BesselI[1, x]*StruveL[0, x])/(x^2*BesselI[2, x]), x -> Infinity]

Comment: Hmm... odd; pasting your code into Mathematica [still gives me 0](https://i.imgur.com/Jy31mne.png).